# NativeScript core on texFieldChange set cursor to end

Tags: javascript, events, nativescript

When fires an textfield textChange and replace or add some content to the string binded the cursor goes to Start (in Android with NativeScript 5.0 Core). Here is the code:

```
page.getViewById("productPrizeTextField")
    .addEventListener("textChange", function () {
      if(mv.productPrize.includes('.')) {
        mv.productPrize = mv.productPrize.replace(".", ",");
      }
      validation();
    })
```

I found that it's an issue, but are there any method to cheat that cursor moving it to the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the default behavior of Android. The workaround is to call `setSelection` method on native text view.

```
....
mv.productPrize = mv.productPrize.replace(".", ",");
if (args.object.android) {

// Where 'args' is argument passed to textChange event
  args.object.android.setSelection(mv.productPrize.length);
}
...
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't develop in pure android  before. That solution works fine for me, lots of thanks